# How can I delete record based on date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a set of data with **DateTime type** in SQL. I want to delete whatever data belong to a specific date for ex: **2021-11-02 21:07:52.663**.
if I have value like above I want to delete records using just date. **2021-11-02**.

Comment: So what have you tried? Maybe `where datecolumn >'20211102' and datecolumn <'20211103'`?

Comment: Note that tables have _rows_, not records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will compare the date part of your datetime to the desired date:

```
DELETE
FROM
    MyTable mt
WHERE
    CAST(mt.MyDate AS DATE) = '2021-11-02'
```

Comment: **DELETE
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    CAST(MyTable.MyDate AS DATE) = '2021-11-02'**

Your solution is worked but it needs to be like this to work.